# Java Client Server with RMI

Tags: java, server, client

Write a Java client-server program applying RMI. The client program generate two arrays of type class Integer. The client calls method that is on the server side in a remote object. The server put these two arrays into one array, sort the array and returns the sorted array to the client. The client displays the sorted array on the console. Use the following interface. Do not change it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.rmi.*;

public interface MergeInterface extends Remote {
  public ArrayList mergeAndSort(ArrayList a, ArrayList b)  throws RemoteException; 
}
```

The following sequential program is putting two arrays together, sorting array and display:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();
    int m = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        a.add(r.nextInt(500) + 10);
    }
    int n = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b.add(r.nextInt(500) + 10);
    }
    a.addAll(b);
    Collections.sort(a);
    for (Integer i : a) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem or error message? stackoverflow is not a "please do my homework for me" service.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement an interface and move the "sequential program" into a method called "mergeAndSort"?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to implement an interface on a class.  I would also consider creating a generic class for this or strongly typing the ArrayLists, but that requires a change to the interface.

```
public interface MergeInterface extends Remote {
    public ArrayList mergeAndSort(ArrayList a, ArrayList b) throws RemoteException;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList b = new ArrayList();
    Random r = new Random();
    int m = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        a.add(r.nextInt(500) + 10);
    }
    int n = r.nextInt(900) + 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        b.add(r.nextInt(500) + 10);
    }

    for (Integer i : (ArrayList<Integer>)new MergeImpl().mergeAndSort(a, b)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static class MergeImpl implements MergeInterface {

    @Override
    public ArrayList mergeAndSort(ArrayList a,
                                  ArrayList b) {
        ArrayList merged = new ArrayList();
        merged.addAll(a);
        merged.addAll(b);
        Collections.sort(merged);
        return merged;
    }
}
```